# Using functions in Python: Wrong length

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

I am trying to use a function to solve a problem. The function is supposed to count the number of digits in a string. This is what I have written:

```
def count_digits(input):
    digits = 0
    for digits in range (len(input)):
        if input.isdigit():
            digits = digits + 1
    return digits
print count_digits("xx87xhyx6x5x00")
```

So in this instance when I print I should be seeing the number 6 pop up in the shell, however, what I am seeing is the length of the string - 1, instead of the number of digits.
Please advise!

Comment: Have you read the code? Have you tried rubber duck debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named the counter and each individual digit in your loop with the same variable.

You are also checking the entire line at once with `input.isdigit()`

In Python, you don't need to know the length of the item to step over it.

Your code and thus be simplified to:

```
def count_digits(input):
    total_digits = 0
    for item in input:
       if item.isdigit():
          total_digits += 1
    return total_digits

>>> print count_digits("xx87xhyx6x5x00")
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Your naming, as others mentioned, is a mess -- and your approach is too low-level.  What about:

```
def count_digits(input):
    return sum(x.isdigit() for x in input)
```

Comment: The question is not about the sum of the digits, it is about the count of digits in the input string. The function name itself is count_digits, and not sum_digits.

Comment: @kvivek, and that's exactly what my code does -- it **counts** digits.  It sums **booleans** (which, seen as integers, are 0 for False, 1 for True), which means exactly "count the items for which the predicate is true".  Where did you get the hallucination that it was **summing** digits?!

Comment: This might be a bit too Pythonic for the OP, but +1 for the compact solution.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to clear up your variable names.

Every iteration on that `for` loop, you're overwriting the `digits` variable to be the current number from range.

change

`for digits` to be `for digit`

Once that change is done, you need to correct this error:

`if input.isdigit():`

This should become

`if digit.isdigit():`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
>>> def count_digits(input):
...     return len([x for x in input if x.isdigit()]
...
>>> print count_digits("xx87xhyx6x5x00")
6
>>>
```